# Gaussian elimination code shows wrong result

Tags: java, matrix

I made this code for Gauss matrix, however the code does not show what it should.

I used `[[0,0,1,2],[2,3,0,-2],[3,3,6,-9]]` as a matrix A, it sorts it fine but when it comes to Gauss I get `[[3.0,3.0,6.0,-9.0],[3.0,5.25,-3.0,0.0],[0,0,1.0,2.0]]`, when the correct answer is `[[3.0,3.0,6.0,-9.0],[0.0,-1.5,6.0,-6.0],[0,0,1.0,2.0]]`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static double[][] sortMatrix(double[][] matrix)
{
    int m=matrix.length;
    int n=matrix[0].length;
    double[] temp=new double[n];
    int a=0;
    for(int fixedCol=a;fixedCol<n;fixedCol++)//Working and fixing the column only.
    {
        for(int fixedRow=a;fixedRow<m;fixedRow++)//First process.
        {
            //Second process.
            for(int i=fixedRow;i<m;i++)//Checking if the column element is bigger.
            {
                if(matrix[fixedRow][fixedCol]<matrix[i][fixedCol])
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    {
                        temp[j]=matrix[fixedRow][j];
                        matrix[fixedRow][j]=matrix[i][j];
                        matrix[i][j]=temp[j];//Until now, changes the row and since fixed row and column points to a value, nothing to change.
                    }
                }
            }//End of second process.
        }
        for(int fixedRow=a;fixedRow<m;fixedRow++)
        {
            if(matrix[fixedRow][fixedCol]!=0)
            {
                a=a+1;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }//End of first process
    return matrix;
}

//Gauss Matrix

public static double[][] gauss(double[][] matrix)
{
    double tempPrincipal,tempSecondary;
    int m=matrix.length;
    int n=matrix[0].length;
    sortMatrix(matrix);
    
    for(int fixedRowPrincipal=0;fixedRowPrincipal<(m-1);fixedRowPrincipal++)
    {
        for(int fixedColPrincipal=0;fixedColPrincipal<n;fixedColPrincipal++)//First process: Finding the first element different from 0.
        {
            if(matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][fixedColPrincipal]!=0)//Found the first element different from 0.
            {
                if(matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][fixedColPrincipal]!=0)//Conditioning the element below isn´t 0.
                {
                    tempPrincipal=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][fixedColPrincipal];//Assigning fixed values for the elements.
                    tempSecondary=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][fixedColPrincipal];
                    for(int j=(fixedColPrincipal);j<n;j++)
                    {
                        if(tempPrincipal<0)
                        {
                            if(tempSecondary<0)
                            {
                                matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][j]+(-1.0)*matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]*(tempPrincipal/tempSecondary);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][j]+(1.0)*matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]*(tempPrincipal/tempSecondary);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(tempSecondary<0)
                            {
                                matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][j]+(1.0)*matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]*(tempPrincipal/tempSecondary);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][j]-(matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]/tempSecondary)*tempPrincipal;
                            }
                        }
                        matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]=matrix[fixedRowPrincipal][j]+(-1)*matrix[fixedRowPrincipal+1][j]*(tempPrincipal/tempSecondary);
                    }
                    sortMatrix(matrix);
                    fixedRowPrincipal=0;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### First Step

Gussian Reduction is all about Row operations so it's better to implement them first, For this we only need a function that takes the matrix, Ri and Rj and a , it adds a*Ri to Rj .

Other Row operations are : switching two rows and multiplying a row by a number, I'll explain latter why we don't need them here :).

### Second Step

Now we want to determine the "pivot element" , assume the matrix `A` is of n*m size, at the first iteration the pivot element is A[0][0], on the second it is A[1][1] .

In short it is `A[i][i]`.

### Third Step

Now we want to change every row after `i` So that `A[r][i]` is zero for every `i+1<=r<n`

We change row `r` so that `A[r]+=(-A[r][i]/A[i][i])*A[i]`, we can call the function from step 1 to do this.

### Fourth Step

We repeat step two and three for every `i<n-1 && i<m` and we're finished.

The variable `i` should be smaller than `n-1` not n because we want to change every row `r` that is `i+1` or more , the row `i=n-1` doesn't have any rows after it.

It should be smaller than `m` because we are also using it as a column number.

### Why only one row operation is enough

The others are used for making the pivot element `1` because 1 is simpler for humans.

But computers don't have problems with numbers other than 1, actually trying to make it `1` will instead hurt performance as it requires additional computations (especially switching Rows).

### Performance step

In Step 3 we have `A[r]+=(-A[r][i]/A[i][i])*A[i]`, this will work even when `A[r][i]` is already zero but because the previous equation is implemented via function call that has `O(n)` complexity, we can avoid calling it altogether by checking if `A[r][i]` is zero, if it is we `continue` the loop in the Fourth step(we can also make the check inside the function that does this operation which is better in my opinion) .

I'll leave the implementation for you, I suggest the function of the first step to have this signature:

```
void addRowToRow(double[][] a,int i,int j,int alpha)
```

It should be called in step 3 like this :

```
addRowToRow(a,i,r,-(a[r][i]/a[i][i]));
```

### Note

I assumed that you only need gaussian reduction and that you don't want an equation solver, anyway the previous steps can be the `reduce(double[][] a)` function which an equation solver can call.